# Using del dict['key'] against django fom.cleaned_data

Tags: python, django, dictionary

As the title states I'm trying to use del against the cleaned data of a Django form.  Pretty standard operation I would think:

```
del form.cleaned_data['user_type']
```

But it's throwing me a remove attribute error:

```
2014-05-12 16:59:24,684 :'dict' object has no attribute 'remove'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/meteorainer/mysite/mysite/myapp/views.py", line 148, in form_valid
    del form.cleaned_data['user_type']
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'remove'
```

Admittedly I'm still new to python, but shouldn't this work without causing any sort of issue?  My understanding is that the alternative of `pop()` works in much the same way, only it returns the value to the key it deletes.  I don't want to use `remove()` specifically because I'm double checking a value and don't know which of several options it could be.

Just to preempt potential questions:

**why are you doing this?**
I'm using a hidden form input to track which way the user is registering, so I can assign groups.  However if I used `form.save()` without getting that input out of there it gets upset.  If you know of a better way to handle that please feel free to chime in.

Comment: Can you post your form and view code? `cleaned_data` is a `dict`, so `del` should work fine. The `AttributeError` suggest there is another problem somewhere.

Comment: I switched to pop, and it's working now. Will update the question will both versions when I can.